# Unable to render an onclick event using React

Tags: reactjs

```
                {children.map(child =>
                    <tr key=...><td>{child.hasChildren && <button onClick={this.handleClick} class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">+</button></td></tr>
                )}
```

For whatever reason I can't get React to render my "onclick" part. It keeps eating it away.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a typo, change **onclick** to **onClick**

```
{children.map(child =>
                <tr key=...>
                    <td><button onClick={this.handleClick}>+</button></td>
                </tr>
            )}
```

Comment: That does not work either. I want react to just render what I've typed. Instead both for onclick=... and onClick=... it removes it.

Comment: Does the button gets rendered?

Comment: yes, I edited my question to change it to onClick. There is some aha moment I'm missing. I basically want to render this button so I can manipulate the real DOM myself. This part of my app has to interface with some legacy code that looks at ids of elements and does modifications to it.

Comment: can you please share SomeCommandToRunInBrowser code? why I am asking is if its a handler, it should be this.SomeCommandToRunInBrowser

Comment: all it does is alert('hello world'); and it's not being called. I think this has to do something with React refs or dangerously setting html or something.

Comment: Can you paste full piece of code please , the full component

Comment: Yes , please paste full component, it will help to answer better

Comment: I have figured it out. It was because of a static function, and the this property was not being respected. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not well-put.

Are asking why the button's onClick event handler (`this.handleClick`) is not invoked?

If so, as long as `this.handleClick` method exists [and properly bounded] in your component, it should be invoked as expected.

Here is an example of how to handle events in React:

```
class Toggle extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {isToggleOn: true};

    // This binding is necessary to make `this` work in the callback
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState(state => ({
      isToggleOn: !state.isToggleOn
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
        {this.state.isToggleOn ? 'ON' : 'OFF'}
      </button>
    );
  }
}
```